# Configuration: DNS or Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, php, cname-record

I have the following problem. I have two domains: www.domain1.de and www.domain2.de I also have path is on Jelastic server where to find my PHP page myphpsite.jelastic.dogado.eu.

Now I wanted to do the following.

1) If I go to www.domain1.de, then should address bar of the Web Browser www.domain1.de be displayed, but the page is fetched from myphpsite.jelastic.dogado.eu.

2) When I go to www.domain2.de, then should address bar of the Web Browser www.domain2.de be displayed, but the page is fetched from myphpsite.jelastic.dogado.eu / admin /.

so

1) www.domain1.de -> myphpsite.jelastic.dogado.eu 2) www.domain2.de -> myphpsite.jelastic.dogado.eu / admin /

The first one I can do by CNAM Record

But we can I solve the second problem without frames?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is what [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) is for, possibly combined with [mod_rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask).